pywinauto: how set text to Search window on the taskbar?
I would like to turn off an annoying application which disturbs the automated testing of AUT, to turn it off on Startup. So I need print "Startup" text to "Search"("Поиск") window in the taskbar, but cannot identify it. I tried dump_tree () and Inspect util w/o any luck.
from pywinauto import Desktop
taskbar = Desktop(backend="uia").window(title="Taskbar", control_type="Pane")
# this step to get "Search" window focused
taskbar.child_window(title="Start", control_type="Button").click_input()
search = Desktop(backend="uia").window(title="Type here to search", control_type="Edit")
search.set_text("Startup")`

please find a screenshot which shows which control I mean: 
Screenshot taken from my localized Windows10. So all controls I used in my code are localized for usage with this Windows version.
here is localized code:
taskbar = Desktop(backend="uia").window(title="Панель задач", control_type="Pane")
# этот шаг чтобы получить фокус окна "Поиск"
taskbar.child_window(title="Пуск", control_type="Button").click_input()
search = Desktop(backend="uia").window(title="Поле поиска", control_type="Edit")
search.set_text("Автозагрузка")

I expect any help please

Using method .type_keys("Startup") should work. This search box may not support programmatic text input. So .type_keys(...) do more realistic input key by key which work in many cases. But it is slower and it requires active desktop (when your PC is not locked or Remote Desktop is not minimized or disconnected). P.S. Maybe you need .click_input() first.

The problem is that I cant identify Search window:
pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: {'title': 'Поле поиска', 'control_type': 'Edit', 'top_level_only': True, 'backend': 'uia'}

I added localized codede above.
